# How to import another workbook into excel with VBA based on header?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I want to importing workbook into my current Excel sheet, now when I imported it is imparting by row order, for example:

Workbook 1:

Header:

Age , Name, Gender, BOD, Country

Workbook 2:

Header:

Name, Gender, Age

in Workbook 1 order of header always in not same

How can I import based on header?

```
Workbooks(MasterWB).Worksheets(MasterSheet).Range("A" & rowMaster).Value = Workbooks(TempWB).Worksheets(TempSheet).Range("A" & row).Value
    Workbooks(MasterWB).Worksheets(MasterSheet).Range("B" & rowMaster).Value = Workbooks(TempWB).Worksheets(TempSheet).Range("B" & row).Value
    Workbooks(MasterWB).Worksheets(MasterSheet).Range("C" & rowMaster).Value =
```

Comment: Your code should work... If you want it to be automatic without the need to write every single column, you need a loop and index headers on both sheets so you know where is each header on both sheets.

Comment: Index on Workbook 1 always changing and I want it to be automatic

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyWorksheet()

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818629/7558682
    'You'll need to check Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference under tools-->references for this to work.
    'Edit workbook and worksheet names to suit your needs.
    'For this to work you need that both headers are called exactly the same.

    Dim arr As Variant, arrTemp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MasterHeaders As New Scripting.Dictionary

    'this will throw the whole worksheet inside an array
    arrTemp = Workbooks("TempWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("TempSheet").UsedRange.Value
    'This will work if the master workbook is the same holding the code
    'change ThisWorkbook for Workbooks("MasterSheet") if not the case.
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")
        ReDim arr(1 To UBound(arrTemp), 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count) 'redim the main array

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            'fill the headers for the final array
            arr(1, i) = .Cells(1, i)
            'fill a dictionary with the header locaton for the final array
            If Not MasterHeaders.Exists(arr(1, i)) And Not arr(1, i) = vbNullString Then _
                MasterHeaders.Add UCase(arr(1, i)), i
        Next i

        'Now fill the final array
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrTemp)
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrTemp, 2)
                If MasterHeaders.Exists(UCase(arrTemp(1, j))) Then arr(i, j) = arrTemp(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        'paste the final array back to the master sheet
        .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))).Value = arr
    End With

End Sub
```